# Show that: $ \frac{x^2}{2(x + 1)} < x − \ln(x + 1) < \frac{x^2}{ 2} , x > 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that: $ \frac{x^2}{2(x + 1)} < x − \ln(x + 1) < \frac{x^2}{ 2} , x > 0$

One method is considering a function $f(x) = x − \ln(1 + x) − \frac{x^2}{2}$ and showing its derivative $f'(x) < 0$.
Similarly, considering another function $g(x) = x − \ln(1 + x) − \frac{x^2}{ 2(x + 1)}$ and showing its $g'(x) > 0$.

Is there some other method that is not lengthy?

Comment: I suppose that's $\frac{x^2}{2(x+1)}$ on the left?

Comment: don't forget the dollar signs when you type the maths!

Comment: Another tip: \$\frac{x^2}{2(x+1)}\$ results in $\frac{x^2}{2(x+1)}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$ \int_0^x\frac{t}{t+1}dt=x-\ln(x+1). $$
Since $f(t)=\frac{1}{t+1}$ is decreasing in $[0,x]$, one has
$$ \frac{x^2}{2(x+1)}=\int_0^x\frac{t}{x+1}dt<\int_0^x\frac{t}{t+1}dt<\int_0^xtdt=\frac12x^2 $$
and hence
$$ \frac{x^2}{2(x+1)}<x-\ln(x+1) <\frac12x^2, x>0.$$

Comment: +1 At first it seems that writing the expression as integral of something is the same as the OP's  taking the derivative. However, the clever difference is in finding useful estimates instead of blind calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can use limits for the natural log (which can basically be seen after Taylor expansion, proof is  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140643/)) to see that

$\ln(x+1) > x - x^2/2$ and $(x+1)\ln(x+1) < x + x^2/2$

The first inequality  immediately gives

$x-\ln(x+1) < x^2/2$  and

and the second one gives

$(x+1) (x-\ln(x+1)) > x + x^2 - (x + x^2/2) = x^2/2$

so we have the two required limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{x+1} & f'(x)&=1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \\
g(x)&=x-\ln(x+1) & g'(x)&=1-\frac{1}{x+1} \\
h(x)&=\frac{x^2}{2} & h'(x)&=x
\end{align}
and note that, for $x>0$,
$$
f'(x)<g'(x)<h'(x)
$$
Since
$$
f(0)=0,\qquad g(0)=0,\qquad h(0)=0
$$
we have derived the stated inequalities.

Not so different from your method, but a bit faster.