# Let $a_n =\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and $b_n =1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$, given $n$ find $k$ so that $a_k \gt b_n$

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

Let $a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and $b_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} +\cdots + \frac{1}{n!}$.

I need to find, for every $n$, a $k$ such that  $a_k \gt b_n$.

I proved, that $b_n \ge a_n$ for every $n$, and both sequences are increasing, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = e$, but I can't use,that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$ and i can't use Taylor series.

Could anyone give me a hint? I have no idea about approaching this...

Comment: Are you supposed to find all $k,n$ such that $a_k>b_n$?

Comment: I have to prove, that following $k$ exists.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you mean for each $n$ there is a $k$ such that $a_k>b_n$?

Comment: Yes, and I have to find this $k$

Comment: Something like $n=1, k \ge 2$; $n=2, k \ge 6$; $n=3, k \ge 26$?

Comment: Yep, but  it is not needed to find the smallest following $k$, just any

Comment: Try something like $k=(n+2)!$

Comment: Hm, good idea, I will try it now

Comment: Do you only need to prove that $k$ exists, or do you need to find a $k$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: Doesn't matter, both of these variants will work

Comment: "I can't use,that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$": do you mean can't or may not ?

Comment: I can't use it in this problem, because this is the key to prove, that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ = $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand using the binomial theorem:

$$a_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i}\frac{1}{k^i}$$

Recall that $\binom{k}{i}=\frac{k(k-1)\cdots(k-(i-1))}{i!}$, so:

$$\binom{k}{i}\frac{1}{k^i}=\frac{(1-0/k)(1-1/k)\cdots(1-(i-1)/k)}{i!}$$

Given $n$, define the polynomial:

$$p_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\cdots(1-(i-1)x)}{i!}$$

Then we have that $p_n(1/k)< a_k$ when $k>n+1$, and $\lim_{x\to 0} p_n(x) =p_n(0)=b_{n+1}>b_n.$

So $p_n$ is continuous, we can find $\delta>0$ such that when $|x|<\delta$, $|p_n(x)-b_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=b_{n+1}-b_n.$

Choose some $k>\frac{1}{\delta}.$

Then $\left|\frac1k\right|<\delta$ and thus $b_n=b_{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}<p_n\left(\frac 1k\right)$. If we pick $k>n$, we also get:

$$b_n < p_n(1/k) < a_k$$

It's not coming to me immediately how we can find a specific $k$, without some pain.

If $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} q_ix^{i}$ let $M=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}|q_i|$. Then $$p_n(x)-p_n(0)=x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} q_ix^{i-1}\right)$$ If $|x|<1$ then $|p_n(x)-p_n(0)|<M|x|$.  So if $\delta=\min(\frac{1}{M(n+1)!},1)$ you can choose $k>\max(1,M(n+1)!)$. Just need an upper bound on $M$ now.

But $p_{n}(-1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} |q_i|$, and $q_0=b_{n+1}$, so we see that $$p_{n}(-1)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{i!}{i!}=n+2$$ Also, $q_0=p_n(0)=b_{n+1}$. So:

$$M=p_{n}(-1)-p_n(0)=n+2-b_{n+1}<n$$

So we can choose $$k>n(n+1)!$$

Comment: Why there is $i$? I can't get it
$$p_n(x)-p_n(0)=x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} iq_ic^{i-1}\right)$$

Comment: Oh, got it, cool

Comment: Removed pointless use of mean value theorem - easier to bound $M$ directly.

Answer (score 1):

$b_n$ is the Taylor series of $f(x) = \exp(x)$ (expanded about x=0) evaluated at $x = 1$ with n terms. [This is just background information, not stricty required.]

We have that  $b_n$ will approach e from below. A simple estimate is

$$
b_n + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} < e
$$
hence $b_n < e -  \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. So it is enough to find a $k$ such that $e -  \frac{1}{(n+1)!} < a_k = (1 + 1/k)^k$.
This is equivalent to $\log(e -  \frac{1}{(n+1)!}) < k \log (1 + 1/k)$.

Since $\log(1+x) > x - x^2/2$ (proof see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140643/)), an even harder requirement is 
$$
\log( e -  \frac{1}{(n+1)!}) < 1 - \frac{1}{2\; k}
$$

This finally gives 
$$
k > 
\frac{-1}{2 \log( 1 -  \frac{1}{e (n+1)!}))}
$$

This is not a nice (or the best) formula, but it shows that a $k$ can always be found.

Comment: I can't use Taylor series, and I can't use, that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$ and differentiation too(

Comment: Question specifically says OP can't use $\lim b_n = e$.

Comment: Questions says $\lim_{x\to \infty} c_n = e$ (whatever $x$ and $c_n$ are) but I guess with some fantasy this means $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$. Strange what one has to guess.

Comment: Anyway I didn't use Taylor, but, yes, I used  $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$. The first simple estimate I used comes without Taylor.

Comment: Ok,  coming back to the proof. Suppose I would (as part of my proof) independently show  that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$, could I use this fact then?

Comment: But this problem is the key for proving $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$...

Comment: I see your point now. You want to establish that $b_n < a_k < e$ and therefore you do not want to use $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = e$.

Comment: Yep, absolutely.
But that is not enough: $b_n < a_k < e$
I have to write, that $b_n \ge a_n$, and this will be a right proof

Answer (score 1):

Using the Taylor series, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\lt e-\frac1{(n+1)!}
$$
Using the Taylor series of the log, we get
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\gt e-\frac e{2n}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\gt e-\frac e{2k}\gt e-\frac1{(n+1)!}\gt\sum_{j=0}^n\frac1{j!}
$$
That is, we want
$$
k\gt\frac e2(n+1)!
$$

Comment: I can't use Taylor series...

Comment: But it is a nice bound for $k$ - I have a feeling that  $k$ must be bigger than $(n+1)!$ for any $n$, but I haven't proven it.