# Under what condition, a function can be upper bounded by its second-order Taylor expansion?

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, approximation, hessian-matrix

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $g(x) = f(a) + \nabla f(a)^\top (x-a) + \frac{1}{2}(x-a)^\top \nabla^2f(a) (x-a)$ be its second-order expansion at $a$. We know that if $f$ is concave, then it can always upper bounded by its first-order expansion.

I was wondering, under what condition (i.e., we can impose additional assumptions on $f$), we can have

$f(x) \le g(x), \quad \forall x,a$?

A trivial solution will be $f(x) = x_0 + w^\top x + x^\top H x$, which gives $g(x) =f(x)$.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140643/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the post and sorry for the delayed response! However, that one is only for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so that the higher order derivative is well-defined. It is not quite straightforward to generalize it to my question.

Comment: Yes but you can use the remainder theorems also in the multivariate case,  , and then generalize the argument  of Martin R's answer: functions with derivatives  with no sign change for all x>0, and with signs alternating with n for all n>0 . Now this must hold  in the multivariable case where "derivative" is  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions