# $\left| \ln(1+u) - u + \frac{u^2}{2} \right|\leq |u| ^3 $ for $| u | \leq \frac{2}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Shall we prove that :
$\left| \ln(1+u) - u + \frac{u^2}{2} \right|\leq |u| ^3 $  for $| u | \leq \frac{2}{3}$

---

My attempt :

Let $s$ be the sign function

$f(u)= u^3 - \ln(1+u) + u - \frac{u^2}{2}$

$f'(u) = s(u) 3 u^2 - \frac{1}{1+u} +1 - u$

If $u >0$, $s(u)=1$

$f'(x) = \frac{ 3 u^2 (1+u) -1 + 1 +u - u - u^2}{1+u} = \frac{3u^3+2u^2}{1+u} = \frac{u^2 (3u+2)}{1+u}$

$f'(u)$ for $u >0$

if $u \leq 0$, $s(u) =-1$ and $f'(u) = \frac{-u^2 (3u+4)}{1+u} <0$

So $f$ is decreasing then increasing, the minimum is $f(0)=0$ so the right inequality is proved.

For the left inequality, let define $\psi(u) = \ln(1+u) -u + \frac{u^2}{2} +s(u) u^3$. For $u>0$, $s(u)=1$ , and $\psi'(u)= \frac{4u^2}{1+u} >0$

For $u<0$, $\psi'(u)= -\frac{2u^2}{1+u} >0$

$\psi$ is decreasing then increasing, the min is $\psi(0)=0$. It proves the left inequality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301275/show-that-left-ln1x-x-fracx22-right-le-frac8x33-for-x-%e2%89%a4

Comment: Hi, I don't think so. Could we rectify my answer ?

Comment: How does your answer relate to the question???

Comment: You're right. I want to study the variations of a function.

Comment: Hi. I made a new solution. It seems better.

Comment: What is the relation between $x$ and $u$?

Comment: Thanks, it is an error, I replaced it by $u$.

Comment: There are still $x$'s hanging around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** By Taylor's formula with Lagrange remainder
$$
\log (1 + u) = u - \frac{{u^2 }}{2} + \frac{{u^3 }}{{3(1 + \xi )^3 }},
$$
where $0\leq \xi\leq u$ for $u\geq0$ and $u\leq\xi\leq 0$ for $-1<u<0$.

Comment: Thanks, it solves immediately the inequality.

Comment: This equation can be solved the same way : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794416/0-leq-u-ln1u-leq-u2-for-mid-u-mid-frac12